# Why is google bigquery api returning a 400 instead of a 500 status code?

Tags: google-bigquery

Why is the following google bigquery api call a 400 "Bad Request" instead of a 500 (or more specifically a 503)?  I typically wouldn't retry a 400, because it implies something was wrong with my request, but when I look at the description in the error message it looks like it is a temporary error on the server side.  Also, when I retried, the response was successful.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The job encountered an error during execution. Retrying the job may solve the problem.",
    "reason" : "jobBackendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "The job encountered an error during execution. Retrying the job may solve the problem."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

I excluded the rest of the proprietary stacktrace, but the code looks like the following, where the SQL was simple like -> "select * from `project.ds.table` order by 1"

```
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest().setQuery(queryString).setUseLegacySql(false).setTimeoutMs(1l);

QueryResponse resp = bq.jobs().query(projectId, request)
        .execute();
```

According to Big Query Docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors and normal HTTP conventions.  I would think that it should be a 500 or 503.

```
backendError    500 or 503  This error returns when there is a temporary server failure such as a network connection problem or a server overload.
```

Comment: Do you have a job ID for the failed execution of the query? That may help a BigQuery engineer to provide more input on what went wrong.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard No, an exception was thrown and that does not appear to be in the exception message.

Comment: I believe that you can also look under "Query History" or "Job History" from the BigQuery UI.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard that's a good tip, but unfortunately I ran the same query many times so I don't know which job it was that failed.  I see many results under Query history, but none under Job History.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am observing this same problem in production, where occasionally this HTTP 400 error message appears. It is raised as a BadRequest exception by the Python library.
This exception appears very rarely and only under heavy load (many concurrent queries running at the same time).

The problem is described on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/23) on the repo of the official Python BigQuery client. An internal Google issue was created and closed as infeasible, with this motivation:

> Connection error is the only retryable error returned as a job result, so you only need to add the logic to retry jobs.insert() if jobs.getQueryResult() returns 400 and the error reason set to the "jobBackendError" (which means that the job failed with the connection error), but I don't think you can reuse the job id for this case.

I have a currently open ticket on Google Support, asking them to change the HTTP status code to 500, or at least to document in the [error table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages) the `jobBackendError` reason.

As a temporary workaround, you could catch all the HTTP 400 exceptions, retry only those with the `jobBackendError`, `backendError`, `internalError` reasons, and re-raise the others.